# How to override private method from a library class

Tags: php, overriding, private

Given are the following classes with class `A` coming from an [external library](https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier) so that I can not change it:

```
class A {
    public function test () {
        $this->privateMethod();
    }
    private function privateMethod () {
        echo('A');
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private function privateMethod () {
        echo('B');
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
```

This results in `A` being printed out by `A::privateMethod` instead of `B` from `B::privateMethod`, because the latter is not visible to `A::test` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756631/948404).

How else can I modify the behavior of this private library method in the cleanest possible way (e.g. without code duplication from copying the whole class and changing it)?

Comment: There are several solutions to this, it might be useful to know which library you are using, assuming it is open source.

Comment: Yes, [it is](https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier). I need to change `getCssFromAllStyleNodes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the behaviour indirectly.  This is the snippet you are interested in.

```
$allCss = $this->css;

if ($this->isStyleBlocksParsingEnabled) {
    $allCss .= $this->getCssFromAllStyleNodes($xpath);
}
```

Looking at the class setters,  you can call `disableStyleBlocksParsing` to prevent the function being called.

The `$allCss` variable is taken straight from `$this->css`, which is only modified by the `setCss` method.

So you have two choices:

- Extend the class, make `isStyleBlocksParsingEnabled` false and immutable, then override the `setCss` method to do what you wanted `getCssFromAllStyleNodes` to do.
- Call `disableStyleBlocksParsing` and and call `setCss` with preprocessed text.

Here is an example of the first option:

```
class MyEmogrifier extends Emogrifier
{
    public function __construct($html = '', $css = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($html, $css);

        $this->disableStyleBlocksParsing();
    }

    public function setCss($css)
    {
        // Preprocess CSS here.

        parent::setCss($css);
    }
}
```

So there is no shotgun surgery, or reflection needed.

To be honest though.  I would feel much less inclined to even use a library as concrete as this one.  I use `protected` for nearly all of my would be private methods.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `private` is only in the scope of the class itself. I you had used `protected` you would've overridden the function, because a `protected` method means it's available for child classes.

Comment: I know why it doesn't work, but I am looking for a different way to achieve what I stated in the question.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. The OP says it's a library so he cannot change the access modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You can change accessibility of a class method using [`ReflectionMethod::setAccessible()`](https://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php):

```
$myEmogrifier = new \Pelago\Emogrifier;
$reflectedMethod = new ReflectionMethod($myEmogrifier, 'getCssFromAllStyleNodes');
$reflectedMethod->setAccessible(true);
$argument = new \DOMXpath(new \DOMDocument);
$returnValue = $reflectedMethod->invoke($myEmogrifier, $argument);
```

Take into account that this code will be 'fragile', since the author of the library will not take into account that a user of the library is relying on the result of a private function. It may be better to simply duplicate the function's code yourself than messing with the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can change hardcode `visibility` of property via [ReflectionClass::setAccessible](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php)
this is a part of [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

> Sets a property to be accessible. For example, it may allow protected
>   and private properties to be accessed.

**It is dangerous** but in some cases you can use it.